# Scanner returning a element not found error, but doesn't hasNext prevent that?

Tags: java, csv

So I have a program that is making a wrestling bracket, and I have it get its input from a CSV file.

```
Alex,Brown,School1,140,10,2,12,10
Bill,Bob,School2,140,8,4,9,3
Ted,Red,School1,140,12,5,5,9
Randy,Ted,School2,140,17,7,10,8
Sam,Mark,School2,140,21,4,10,8
Noel,Frank,School2,140,7,8,10,8
```

However, when I have the scanner go through, it goes through it all, and for some reason the debug output prints out zeros between the first names, and then doesn't stop, even though the while loop is set to stop when the hasNext() method returns false.

My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.Object;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bracket_Creator{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   

        String first_name = "";
        String last_name = "";
        String school = "";
        int weight = 0;
        int confer_win = 0;
        int confer_loss = 0;
        int overall_wins = 0;
        int overall_loss = 0;
        ArrayList<Wrestler> list = new ArrayList<Wrestler>();
        int i = 0;
        boolean flag = true;

        //new scanner instance
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("wrestlers.csv"));

        //the seperator for the file
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            first_name = scanner.next();
            last_name = scanner.next();
            school = scanner.next();
            weight = scanner.nextInt();
            confer_win = scanner.nextInt();
            confer_loss = scanner.nextInt();
            overall_wins = scanner.nextInt();
            overall_loss = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(new Wrestler(first_name,last_name,school,weight,
                confer_win,confer_loss,overall_wins,overall_loss));

            System.out.println((list.get(i).get_first_name()));
            i++;


        }//end while
        scanner.close();



        //make the percentages for the wrestlers
        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            (list.get(i)).determine_conf_percentage((list.get(i)).get_confer_wins(), (list.get(i)).get_confer_losses());
            (list.get(i)).determine_overall_percentage((list.get(i)).get_overall_wins(), (list.get(i)).get_overall_losses());

        }//end for loop
        //set rank
        while ( flag )
        {
            flag= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
            for( i=0;  i < list.size() -1;  i++ )
            {
                   if ((list.get(i)).get_confer_percentage() < (list.get(i+1)).get_confer_percentage() )  
                   {

                        Collections.swap(list, i, i+1);
                        flag = true;

                    }//end if
            }//end for 

        }//end while

        //set rank value
        for (i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            (list.get(i)).set_rank(i + 1);
        }//end for loop

        for (i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
        }
            System.out.println("");

        /*
        *
        *
        *Create the Bracket!
        *
        *
        */
        int j = 1; //J here is for the end of the list, every time you go through
        //add one to J in the loop to keep on coming in from the other end of
        //the list
        for (i = 0; i< (list.size()/2); i++){
            if (i == 0) {//first pass thru the list
                System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println((list.get(list.size()-j)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println();
                j++;
                }//end if

            else{
                System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println((list.get(list.size()-j)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println();
                j++;

                }//end else

        }//end for




    }//end main


}//end bracket_creator class
```

And here is the Wrestler class code, for reference:

```
public class Wrestler {

   private String first_name = "";
   private String last_name = "";
   private String school = "";
   private int weight_class = 0;
   private int confer_wins = 0;
   private int confer_losses = 0;
   private int overall_wins = 0;
   private int overall_losses = 0;
   private double confer_percentage = 0;
   private double overall_percentage = 0;
   private int rank;

   /* Constructors! */

   public Wrestler(String init_first_name, String init_last_name, 
   String init_school, int init_weight_class, int init_confer_wins, 
   int init_confer_losses, int init_overall_wins, int init_overall_losses) {

      first_name = init_first_name;
      last_name = init_last_name;
      school = init_school;
      weight_class = init_weight_class;
      confer_wins = init_overall_wins;
      confer_losses = init_confer_losses;
      overall_wins = init_overall_wins;
      overall_losses = init_overall_losses;
      confer_percentage = 0;
      overall_percentage = 0;
      rank = 0;


   }//end wresler constructor




   /*
   *
   *
   *  setters 
   *
   */

    public void set_first_name(String new_first_name){

      first_name = new_first_name; 

    }//end first name setter

    public void set_last_name(String new_last_name){

      last_name = new_last_name; 

    }//end last name setter

    public void set_school(String new_school){

      school = new_school;

    }//end school setter

    public void set_weight_class(int new_weight_class){

      weight_class = new_weight_class; 

    }//end weight class setter

    public void set_conf_wins(int new_conf_wins){

      confer_wins = new_conf_wins; 

    }//end conference wins setter

    public void set_conf_losses(int new_conf_losses){

      confer_losses = new_conf_losses; 

    }//end conference losses setter

    public void set_over_wins(int new_over_wins){

      overall_wins = new_over_wins; 

    }//end over wins setter

    public void set_over_losses(int new_over_losses){

      overall_losses = new_over_losses; 

    }//end over losses setter

    public void set_confer_percentage(double new_confer_percentage){

       confer_percentage = new_confer_percentage;

    }//end conference percentage setter

    public void set_overall_percentage(double new_overall_percentage){

       overall_percentage = new_overall_percentage;

    }//end overall percentage setter

    public void set_rank(int new_rank){

      rank = new_rank; 

    }//end rank setter

    /*
    *
    *
    *  Getters
    *
    */

    public String get_first_name(){

        return first_name;
    }//end first name

    public String get_last_name(){

        return first_name;
    } //end last name

    public String get_school(){
        return school;
    }

    public int get_weight_class(){

        return weight_class;
    }//end weight class

    public int get_confer_wins(){

        return confer_wins;
    }

    public int get_confer_losses(){

        return confer_losses;
    }

    public int get_overall_wins(){
        return overall_wins;
    }

    public int get_overall_losses(){
        return overall_losses;
    }

    public double get_confer_percentage(){
        return confer_percentage;
    }

    public double get_overall_percentage(){
        return overall_percentage;
    }

    public int get_rank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public void determine_conf_percentage(int confer_wins, int confer_losses){

      double determined_percentage = 0;

      if (confer_losses + confer_wins < 4){

          set_confer_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }
      else {
        //note: the 1.0 converts the ints to doubles.
        determined_percentage =  100 * ((1.0*confer_losses) / ((1.0*confer_wins) + (1.0 * confer_losses)));
        set_confer_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }     

    }// end determine_conf_percetnage

    public void determine_overall_percentage(int overall_wins, int overall_losses){

      double determined_percentage = 0;

      if (overall_losses + overall_wins < 4){

          set_overall_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }
      else {
        //note: the 1.0 converts the ints to doubles.
        determined_percentage = 100 * ((1.0*overall_losses) / ((1.0*overall_wins) + (1.0 * overall_losses)));
        set_overall_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }     

    }// end determine_conf_percetnage





}//end Wrestlerpublic class Wrestler {

   private String first_name = "";
   private String last_name = "";
   private String school = "";
   private int weight_class = 0;
   private int confer_wins = 0;
   private int confer_losses = 0;
   private int overall_wins = 0;
   private int overall_losses = 0;
   private double confer_percentage = 0;
   private double overall_percentage = 0;
   private int rank;

   /* Constructors! */

   public Wrestler(String init_first_name, String init_last_name, 
   String init_school, int init_weight_class, int init_confer_wins, 
   int init_confer_losses, int init_overall_wins, int init_overall_losses) {

      first_name = init_first_name;
      last_name = init_last_name;
      school = init_school;
      weight_class = init_weight_class;
      confer_wins = init_overall_wins;
      confer_losses = init_confer_losses;
      overall_wins = init_overall_wins;
      overall_losses = init_overall_losses;
      confer_percentage = 0;
      overall_percentage = 0;
      rank = 0;


   }//end wresler constructor




   /*
   *
   *
   *  setters 
   *
   */

    public void set_first_name(String new_first_name){

      first_name = new_first_name; 

    }//end first name setter

    public void set_last_name(String new_last_name){

      last_name = new_last_name; 

    }//end last name setter

    public void set_school(String new_school){

      school = new_school;

    }//end school setter

    public void set_weight_class(int new_weight_class){

      weight_class = new_weight_class; 

    }//end weight class setter

    public void set_conf_wins(int new_conf_wins){

      confer_wins = new_conf_wins; 

    }//end conference wins setter

    public void set_conf_losses(int new_conf_losses){

      confer_losses = new_conf_losses; 

    }//end conference losses setter

    public void set_over_wins(int new_over_wins){

      overall_wins = new_over_wins; 

    }//end over wins setter

    public void set_over_losses(int new_over_losses){

      overall_losses = new_over_losses; 

    }//end over losses setter

    public void set_confer_percentage(double new_confer_percentage){

       confer_percentage = new_confer_percentage;

    }//end conference percentage setter

    public void set_overall_percentage(double new_overall_percentage){

       overall_percentage = new_overall_percentage;

    }//end overall percentage setter

    public void set_rank(int new_rank){

      rank = new_rank; 

    }//end rank setter

    /*
    *
    *
    *  Getters
    *
    */

    public String get_first_name(){

        return first_name;
    }//end first name

    public String get_last_name(){

        return first_name;
    } //end last name

    public String get_school(){
        return school;
    }

    public int get_weight_class(){

        return weight_class;
    }//end weight class

    public int get_confer_wins(){

        return confer_wins;
    }

    public int get_confer_losses(){

        return confer_losses;
    }

    public int get_overall_wins(){
        return overall_wins;
    }

    public int get_overall_losses(){
        return overall_losses;
    }

    public double get_confer_percentage(){
        return confer_percentage;
    }

    public double get_overall_percentage(){
        return overall_percentage;
    }

    public int get_rank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public void determine_conf_percentage(int confer_wins, int confer_losses){

      double determined_percentage = 0;

      if (confer_losses + confer_wins < 4){

          set_confer_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }
      else {
        //note: the 1.0 converts the ints to doubles.
        determined_percentage =  100 * ((1.0*confer_losses) / ((1.0*confer_wins) + (1.0 * confer_losses)));
        set_confer_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }     

    }// end determine_conf_percetnage

    public void determine_overall_percentage(int overall_wins, int overall_losses){

      double determined_percentage = 0;

      if (overall_losses + overall_wins < 4){

          set_overall_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }
      else {
        //note: the 1.0 converts the ints to doubles.
        determined_percentage = 100 * ((1.0*overall_losses) / ((1.0*overall_wins) + (1.0 * overall_losses)));
        set_overall_percentage(determined_percentage);
      }     

    }// end determine_conf_percetnage





}//end Wrestler
```

Comment: Q: Why are you parsing for 8 elements (3 strings, 5 ints) ... even though your input has *nine* elements (6 ints, not 5)?

Comment: Junk code that I thought I deleted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Q: does it work now that your code matches the .csv input format?  Q: Have you stepped through the code under the debugger, to see the results of each "scanner.next()" and each "scanner.nextInt()"?

Comment: Currently, I decided to use a BufferedReader approach, it uses less code, and is a bit more precise in what I want to do.  Still implementing it as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check hasNext() before everytime you call scanner.next()
so your
    first_name = scanner.next()

statement will never fail, but after this statement executes, you don't check scanner.hasNext()

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `0` at the end of your csv

```
Alex,Brown,School1,140,10,2,12,10,0
```

that isn't meant to be read by anything in the loop.

On the first loop iteration, it won't be read, but on the second it will be read by

```
first_name = scanner.next();
```

since the delimiter is `,`. This keeps going until the last iteration where you will still have a

```
0
```

in the buffer and therefore `hasNext()` will return `true`. This will read it

first_name = scanner.next();

and then there is nothing left in

```
last_name = scanner.next();
```

so the exception is thrown.

What you could simply do is add a simple

```
scanner.nextInt()
```

at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the issue

```
        //the seperator for the file
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            first_name = scanner.next();
            last_name = scanner.next();
            school = scanner.next();
            weight = scanner.nextInt();
            confer_win = scanner.nextInt();
            confer_loss = scanner.nextInt();
            overall_wins = scanner.nextInt();
            overall_loss = scanner.nextInt();
            list.add(new Wrestler(first_name,last_name,school,weight,
                confer_win,confer_loss,overall_wins,overall_loss));

            System.out.println((list.get(i).get_first_name()));
            i++;
```

hasNext() will only check for if another delimiter exists, not if all 9 of your next scans will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.lang.Object;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;  
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bracket_Creator{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   

        String first_name = "";
        String last_name = "";
        String school = "";
        int weight = 0;
        int confer_win = 0;
        int confer_loss = 0;
        int overall_wins = 0;
        int overall_loss = 0;
        ArrayList<Wrestler> list = new ArrayList<Wrestler>();
        int i = 0;
        boolean flag = true;

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String splitBy = ",";

        //new scanner instance

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wrestlers.csv"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){

                String[] attributes = line.split(splitBy);

                list.add(new Wrestler(attributes[0],attributes[1],attributes[2],
                    Integer.parseInt(attributes[3]),
                    Integer.parseInt(attributes[4]),
                    Integer.parseInt(attributes[5]),
                    Integer.parseInt(attributes[6]),
                    Integer.parseInt(attributes[7])));



            }//end while

        }//end try
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null){
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //make the percentages for the wrestlers
        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            (list.get(i)).determine_conf_percentage((list.get(i)).get_confer_wins(), (list.get(i)).get_confer_losses());
            (list.get(i)).determine_overall_percentage((list.get(i)).get_overall_wins(), (list.get(i)).get_overall_losses());

        }//end for loop
        //set rank
        while ( flag )
        {
            flag= false;    //set flag to false awaiting a possible swap
            for( i=0;  i < list.size() -1;  i++ )
            {
                   if ((list.get(i)).get_confer_percentage() < (list.get(i+1)).get_confer_percentage() )  
                   {

                        Collections.swap(list, i, i+1);
                        flag = true;

                    }//end if
            }//end for 

        }//end while

        //set rank value
        for (i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            (list.get(i)).set_rank(i + 1);
        }//end for loop

        for (i = 0; i< list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
        }
            System.out.println("");

        /*
        *
        *
        *Create the Bracket!
        *
        *
        */
        int j = 1; //J here is for the end of the list, every time you go through
        //add one to J in the loop to keep on coming in from the other end of
        //the list
        for (i = 0; i< (list.size()/2); i++){
            if (i == 0) {//first pass thru the list
                System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println((list.get(list.size()-j)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println();
                j++;
                }//end if

            else{
                System.out.println((list.get(i)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println((list.get(list.size()-j)).get_first_name());
                System.out.println();
                j++;

                }//end else

        }//end for




    }//end main


}//end bracket_creator class
```

Worked out, and I got an exception handler in it.